# コミット時にコミットIDをファイルに自動出力させたい

Tags: git, git-bash

現在、VSCodeを使ってGit管理を行っています。

管理時には添付画像のようにコミットIDが出力されますが、「コミットと同時に、自動でコミットIDをテキストファイルに出力」したいと思っています。このようなことはできるのでしょうか?
もし可能であれば、方法を教えていただきたいです。

[image]

下記URLを参考に、`$ git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" > commitID.txt` のようなコマンドを使えば、コミットIDをテキストファイルに出力できることは分かりました。

[現在ブランチのコミットIDをファイル出力](https://kakkoyakakko2.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/18/120000)

ただし、「コミットと同時に自動で」コミットIDをテキストファイルに出力することができないので困っています。(上記方法の場合、git bashを開いてコードを記入する必要がある)

自動で出力できる方法を教えていただけないでしょうか?

「リポジトリにファイルをコミットした際、自動でコミットIDをテキストファイルに出力」が可能であれば、使用エディタはVSCodeに限りません。
(GitHub, Git Bash, GitLab等)
テキストファイルの出力場所にも指定はありません。

ご回答のほど、何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

hooksを使えば簡単に実装できます。

`.git/hooks/`に`post-commit`を作成して以下のように記述すればOKです。
コミット実行後に`post-commit`が呼び出されます。

```
#!/bin/sh

git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" >> commitID.txt
```

- 参考リンク

  - [8.3 Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。git初心者でして、hooksの機能自体を知らなかったので、大変助かりました。ありがとうございます。

ご教授いただいた方法を使用して、自動出力を試みてみます。
何卒宜しくお願いいたします。